# C++ sizeof wrapper class

Tags: c++, class, sizeof

Suppose I have a class A that does not inherit from anything, has no virtual methods, and has exactly one variable of type T. Does C++ guarantee `sizeof(A) == sizeof(T)`?

EDIT:

Also if T were a composite type, would it make a difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it might be more than `sizeof(T)` due to padding.

Comment: Shouldn't `T` get the same padding?

Comment: @SLaks, individual variables don't get padding, only the containing structure (or stack space). To be sure `sizeof(A.var) == sizeof(T)` always.

Comment: Have you ever seen this in the wild? Padding is typically used when a struct has more than member and it should be possible to create an array of structs without it's members ending up on unaligned locations. I would put my money on that this is always true, even though I have to dig into the standard in order to prove it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that implementations are allowed to add comedy padding to the end of structs for absolutely no good reason. Obviously, successful implementations tend not to.

Comment: @Lindydancer: I hate the `In the real world` quotes. It makes no sense. If you  program by what is `Currently` the real world situation rather then by the `standard` your code is just broken. Normally because your `real world` is usually very limited does not take into account future research and ultimately will cause cause a catastrophic failure that will be practically imposable to debug when you port the code to a new architecture/compiler were your assumptions no longer hold.

Comment: Give a example for 'might be'

Comment: Any optimizations which results in `A` benefiting from padding would apply equally well to `T`, so this hypothetical compiler would almost certainly do so, resulting in `sizeof(T) == sizeof(A)`.  I see RTTI being a much more "plausible" cause for seemingly arbitrary size increases.  If a compiler tacks type information of some sort onto some/all non-polymorphic types in order to optimize the polymorphic cases, things could get odd.

Comment: However, the standard doesn't just let the compiler do whatever it wants with structures; it places several limitations on how they are laid out, and places even more limitations on how POD types are laid out.  C++11 goes even further.  If `T` is a fairly simple type [a primitive, for instance], the freedom to apply these hypothetical optimizations is small.  I say make the assumption, and throw a `static_assert(sizeof(T) == sizeof(A));` somewhere on the off chance it stops being safe.

Comment: @Dennis: indeed, code that fails to compile on some obscure strange platform is a lot better than code that compiles and has UB on some obscure strange platform.

Comment: @Naveen: sure about this? `A` and `T` are guaranteed to have the same alignment requirements, which means that padding is, by definition, unnecessary . I can't remember the exact wording, but is the compiler allowed to insert padding where it's not necessary? It might be, but it would be absurd for this to happen in practice.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it explicitly *guarantees* it, but I don't think it would ever be different.

Comment: @John what makes you think so? If you have some evidence then I will definitely delete this answer.

Comment: @Seth:  Actually, I'm reconsidering this assertion.

Comment: @John: I would really like to see an environment where this is true! I don't see any reason why a compiler would add padding to a struct/class with exactly one member.

Comment: @Lindy:  Consider if that one member is not a primitive type.  That's where my mind went.

Comment: @John: How would that increase padding? The type itself would already have its padding. (Talking pragmatically, of course.)

Comment: @John I just tried it with a couple types from the STL and they were all the same (MSVC++ 2010, Windows 7).

Comment: Making the assumption will break somthing when the compiler people invite super optimization X that makes your assumption no longer valid. Just because `you` can't think of a logical reason does not mean anything. Unless you are a compiler engineer you literally have very little understanding of even a fraction of the real world tricks they are performing underneath the surface.

Comment: @Martin: C++ is already published many years, even compiler people invite some "super optimization X", you can still use the old version of compiler to compile your "assumption". I am sure they don't dare to update all versions of compiler to break customer's code only for adding a "supper optimization X".

Comment: @Huang F. Lei: That's exactly what they do because they expect people to write standard compliant code that makes no assumptions. Writing code make assumptions on how the compiler works is silly unprofessional and just asking for trouble.

Answer (score -1):

I think C++ should guarantee sizeof(A) == sizeof(T).

Consider bellow situation, C++ should make it works just like in C:

```
A a[10];
T t[10];

A * ap = (A *) t;
T * tp = (T *) a;

memcpy(ap, tp, sizeof(*ap));
```

Comment: There are a lot of UBs, but UB is not random. Please read author's question again, and tell me which part will cause the UB you mentioned.

Comment: The `memcpy` when it uses the pointers that point to the wrong types.

Comment: Because A only contains T, they should have same memory layout.

Comment: @HuangF.Lei I think that begs the question.