# Will structs with only "double" element have padding?

Tags: c++, padding, memory-alignment

Assume I have a C/C++ struct

```
struct ABCTYPE
{
  double A;
  double B;
  double C;
};
```

Is it ensured to have no extra padding on any kind of modern platforms?

To be more specific, if I use

```
std::vector<ABCTYPE> storage;
// add some elements

// now i need some C routines to the data
double* param=&(storage[0]);
c_routine(param);  // Tested OK on Win/Linux, but will it work on any platforms?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is technically possible for such a struct to have padding. Even the simple case of a struct containing only one member can have padding:

[C++ sizeof wrapper class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994302/c-sizeof-wrapper-class)

Comment: Yes. But I am wondering what will happen if I am using pure double. In my mind double should not pad since it has 8 bytes, 64-bits and have perfect alighment for both 32-bit and 64-bit and even 128-bit systems.

Comment: It doesn't matter. I, as a compiler writer, could implement C++ where all classes/structs pad structs with useless memory if I wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual C++ it is possible to use `#pragma pack` to change the padding of a structure; the value can be set to more than `sizeof(double)` which is 8. The documentation shows an example of setting it to 16.

Comment: -1. IMO, while technically correct, this answer is misleading. As pointed out in my answer, if you set the padding to 16, a member of size 8 will still only be aligned to an address that's a multiple of 8.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your *specific* question about `std::vector` goes, the answer to whether the equivalence you ask about above is valid can be found [in this stackoverflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849168/are-stdvector-elements-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous).

Comment: No. std::vector is guaranteed to be continuous. However, the struct itself might have padding.

Answer (score 0):

In theory it's possible. In reality, I'd be somewhat surprised to see it (though if, for example, you changed the type from `double` to `short`, padding would become rather less surprising).

With MS VC, `#pragma pack` only causes alignment to (at most) the size of the object: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx):

> n (optional)
>
> Specifies the value, in bytes, to be used for packing. The default value for n is 8. Valid values are 1, 2, 4, 8, and 16. The alignment of a member will be on a boundary that is either a multiple of n or a multiple of the size of the member, **whichever is smaller.** [emphasis added]

This means a struct containing multiple members of the same type will never have padding inserted between them. `#pragma pack` controls the *maximum* amount of padding that can be inserted, not the minimum.