# Will the encapsulation of a native type impact on efficiency?

Tags: c++, performance, inline, encapsulation, abstraction

I'd like to encapsulate a `float` in two structures for example:

```
struct AngleDeg {
    explicit AngleDeg(float angle):value(angle) {}
    float value;
};

struct AngleRad {
    explicit AngleRad(float angle):value(angle) {}
    float value;
};
```

Then in a class overload a function using these structs, something like:

```
...
void DoStuff(AngleRad angle);
inline void DoStuff(AngleDeg angle) { DoStuff(Deg2Rad(angle.value)); }
...
```

Will this be as efficient as using the following two functions ?

```
void DoStuffRad(float angle);
inline void DoStuffDeg(float angle) { DoStuffRad(Deg2Rad(angle)); }
```

Comment: Why not write a program that has all the above code in it which measures the performance of each?

Comment: I made a benchmark and posted my conclusion in answers.

Answer (score 5):

It is likely not to affect the runtime speed of your program, but can increase the odds of making the program correct. That's efficient!

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to say for sure. If you want to be 100% sure, check the generated assembly (or just time the execution of the code).

However, two observations that might help you:

- first, your `struct` has the same size as a `float`, so there's no wasted space. And there is no unnecessary indirection: the contained `float` can be accessed as efficiently as before. So there's no fundamental reason why it should be slower
- however, it is possible that this might throw off certain compiler optimizations. Perhaps it simply generates different code for `struct`s than for built-in types in some cases. Or perhaps it uses a different calling convention for `floats` than for "objects which are the size of a `float`".

So maybe, maybe not. But it's unlikely that the speed difference will make a measurable difference.

Comment: Your first point is not guaranteed by the standard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994302/c-sizeof-wrapper-class

Comment: True, practically none of this is *guaranteed*. But in practice, it'll be the case

Answer (score 1):

I thought the same as @jalf for space and access however wasn't sure. So I listened to @quamrana and @jalf, and made a runtime test.

In debug mode, the approach with structs is about 30% slower however in release mode they are equivalent. It may be compiler dependent but I will use the approach with structs.

Comment: This is not surprising: compilers will not inline functions in "debug mode" (whatever that means) so that you can have a stack trace should something go wrong.

Comment: By debug mode, I meant without optimization. The impact of the approach while debugging should be stressed because it can be a bottleneck when debugging real-time applications.

Comment: That sounds about right. Wrapping in a struct means that the optimizer has to work a little bit harder. It can do that (so release builds are unaffected), but in debug builds, where the optimizer is disabled, you take a performance hit.

Comment: If you find it messes up time profiles or w/e, you can optimize just the one file (and leave out its debug info) and see if it changes anything.

Comment: @trinithis: it is not generally a matter of debug information (they are in separate sections of the library, and only loaded on demand). It is just that, as Alexandre C pointed out, to obtain proper stack traces the inline functions are not, in fact, inlined in most Debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

This question was investigated in a [Technical Report on C++ Performance](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/TR18015.pdf). See appendix D.3 for the Stepanove Abstraction Penalty Benchmark. To quote

> The structure of the benchmark is really quite simple. It adds 2000 
>   doubles in an array 25000 times. It does it in 13 different ways that 
>   introduce more and more abstract ways of doing it:
>   0 - uses simple
>   Fortran-like for loop.
>   1 - 12 use STL style accumulate template
>   function with plus function object.
>   1, 3, 5, 7 ,9, 11 use doubles. 
>   2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 use Double - double wrapped in a class.
>   1, 2 - use
>   regular pointers.
>   3, 4 - use pointers wrapped in a class.
>   5, 6 - use
>   pointers wrapped in a reverse-iterator adaptor.
>   7, 8 - use wrapped
>   pointers wrapped in a reverse-iterator adaptor.
>   9, 10 - use pointers
>   wrapped in a reverse-iterator adaptor wrapped in a    reverse-iterator
>   adaptor.
>   11, 12 - use wrapped pointers wrapped in a reverse-iterator
>   adaptor wrapped in a  reverse-iterator adaptor.

Output on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/OfSeD): the abstraction penalty (geometric mean of all 13 tests) for a modern compiler (gcc 4.5.1) is less than 1%.

Answer (score 0):

For any compiler worth your money (even if it is free), it will have no overhead over using a plain float.